# printing elements in a nice format

Tags: java, perl, list, printing

I have a simple, general question regarding a real small issue that bothers me:
I'm printing a list of elements on the fly, so I don't have prior knowledge about the number of printed elements. I want a simple format where the elements are separated by a comma (elem1, elem2...) or something similar. Now, if I use a simple loop like:

```
while(elements to check) {
  if (elem should be printed) {
     print elem . ","
  }
}
```

I get a comma after the last element...
I know this sounds quite stupid, but is there a way to handle this?

Comment: What language are you using? What platform?

Comment: perl, java - i have the same issue in both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a comma BEFORE each element (but the first one)? Pseudo-code:

```
is_first = true
loop element over element_array
BEGIN LOOP
   if (! is_first)
       print ","
   end if
   print element
   is_first = false
END
print NEWLINE
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the "is_first" variable to false.  Otherwise, you'll never print that comma :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that "should be printed" means "at least one non-whitespace character. In Perl, the idiomatic way to write this would be (you'll need to adjust the grep to taste):

```
print join "," => grep { /\S/ } @elements;
```

The "grep" is like "filter" in other languages and the /S/ is a regex matching one non-whitespace character.  Only elements matching the expression are returned. The "join" should be self-explanatory.

```
perldoc -f join
perldoc -f grep
```

Comment: isn't it unecessary to do the grep thing, as 
--  print join ',', @elements --
just do the whole thing perfectly ?
i just ask, to improve my own knowledge

Comment: benzebuth: the grep is only there to filter out undesired elements. However, you're correct that it could be dropped in the case the original poster mentioned.  I typed too fast.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

the way of having all your data in an array and then

```
 print join(',', @yourarray)
```

is a good one.

You can also, after looping for your concatenation

```
declare eltToPrint
 while (LOOP on elt) {
       eltToPrint .= elt.','
}
```

remove the last comma with a regex :

```
eltToPrint =~s/,$//;
```

ps : works also if you put the comma at the beginning

```
eltToPrint =~s/^,//;
```

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have a build-in `join`, but if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can use [Guava's `Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html). It can `skipNulls`, or `useForNull(something)`.

> An object which joins pieces of text (specified as an array, `Iterable`, varargs or even a `Map`) with a separator. It either appends the results to an [`Appendable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) or returns them as a `String`. Example:
>
> ```
> Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("; ").skipNulls();
> return joiner.join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");
> ```
>
> This returns the string `"Harry; Ron; Hermione"`. Note that all input elements are converted to strings using `Object.toString()` before being appended.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options depending on language.

e.g. in JavaScript just do:

```
var prettyString = someArray.join(', ');
```

in PHP you can `implode()`

```
$someArray = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear');
$prettyString = implode(",", $someArray);
```

if all else fails, you can either add the comma after every entry and trim the last one when done, or check in you while/foreach loop (bad for perf) if this is not the last item (if so, add a comma)

***update:*** since you noted Java... you could create a method like this:

```
public static String join(String[] strings, String separator) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) sb.append(separator);
      sb.append(strings[i]);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

***update 2:*** sounds like you really want this then if you are not outputting every element (pseudo-code):

```
first = true;
for(item in list){
  if(item meets condition){
    if(!first){
      print ", ";
    } else {
      first = false;
    }
    print item;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I must be missing something... what data do you have to start with? e.g. several strings, a string array?, an ArrayList of Strings? or a Map or similar Object with keys/values?

Comment: It does not really maater, the point is I don't print the entire array/list; I check every element vs. some condition then decide whether I print it or not. So at the time of printing an element, I cannot tell if it's the last one to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest way is to create a new array containing only the elements from the original array that you need to print (i.e. a `filter` operation). Then print the newly created array, preferably using your language's built-in array/vector print/join function.

(In Perl)

```
@orig=("a","bc","d","ef","g");
@new_list=();
for $x(@orig){
    push(@new_list,$x) if (length($x)==1);
}
print join(',',@new_list)."\n";
```

(In Java)

```
List<String> orig=Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","bc","d","ef","g"});
List<String> new_list=new ArrayList<String>();
for(String x: orig){
    if (x.length()==1)
        new_list.add(x);
}
System.out.println(new_list);
```

Comment: Perl example is needlessly complicated, and not strict-safe.
Much better and easier:

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use 5.010;

    my @orig=("a","bc","d","ef","g");
    say join(', ', grep { length > 1 } @orig);

- Michael